# Sort news by date from several profiles

Tags: php, wordpress

I have several profiles that allow users to post news that I want to display in one long feed, sorted in date order.

At the moment this loops through each profile, lists the news from that profile then moves onto the next profile, lists their news and so on. It doesn't mix it all up.

How can I mix all the news together from each profile and order it by date?

```
<?php global $post;
$args = array('numberposts' => -1);
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
   <?php while(the_repeater_field('news')): ?>
      <div class="social-news-item">
         <p class="social-news"><?php the_sub_field('news_description'); ?></p>
     <p class="social-company"><?php echo the_title(); ?></p>
      </div>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
<? endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

The date field is:

`<?php the_sub_field('date'); ?>`

Comment: I don't know wordpress and maybe it is a stupid question, but is it possible to get all posts first into one array and then sort them?

Comment: @Voitcus The loop in the question gets all the posts, just not sure how to put into into array and sort by the date?

Comment: I will type it in an answer, because I have no space here, but do not consider it as the answer.

Comment: Hi Rob, I would like to ask you to specify your question, because is not clear. First of all I assume you're using ACF plugin as "the_repeater_field" is a function (deprecated) by that plugin.

Comment: Sorry I've sent the comment by mistake. This is my full thought:
In the snippet you've pasted you should get every single post in your wp as the only argument you specify in the get_posts is numberpost => -1. But I think the most important thing you should clearify is what you intend with "news". Surely not a category or a taxonomy, as in your snippet you use "the_repeater_field('news')" that is a function by ACF plugin (deprecated, you should use has_sub_field instead).
Then you print only the posts that has the_repeater_field 'news'.
Do you want to mix in a feed different Custom Post Types?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the order programmatically, have a look at the various [array sorting functions in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php), especially

- `uasort()`— Sort an array with a user-defined comparison function and maintain index association
- `uksort()`— Sort an array by keys using a user-defined comparison function
- `usort()`— Sort an array by values using a user-defined comparison function

but for wordpress checkout this http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

**Example in given link:**

**Default:**

```
<?php 
   $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'  => 5,
    'numberposts'     => 5,
    'offset'          => 0,
    'category'        => '',
    'orderby'         => 'post_date',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'include'         => '',
    'exclude'         => '',
    'meta_key'        => '',
    'meta_value'      => '',
    'post_type'       => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'  => '',
    'post_parent'     => '',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true );
 ?>
```

**Use:**

```
 <?php $posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>
```

may this help you.

Comment: The news isn't a post (so can't go by the post date), a post is a profile that has a custom field called news.

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote in the comment, I don't know wordpress and maybe something is wrong, but the idea might be ok.

If it is possible, you can first get all posts together and then sort them.

To group them use a temporary array in which you fetch objects. So don't output your `div`s but "buffer" them in the array.

For example, if the array name would be `$posts` you can do in your `foreach` loop:
(I hope in the line with `the_sub_field('news_description');` you missed `echo`, in that case it won't work)

```
$var = &$posts[]; // this creates a new item in array, and $var is this element
$var->description = the_sub_field('news_description'); // *****
$var->title = the_title();
$var->date = ... // it is important, I don't know if you have it
```

So at the end your array will have all the posts from all users (or profiles). Now sort itfor example by using the [usort function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). You will need to write own sorting function, in the manual it is "cmp", so I use the same name:

```
function cmp($a, $b){
  if($a->date > $b->date)
    return 1;
  elseif($a->date < $b->date)
    return -1;
  else
    return 0;
}
```

and call it

```
usort($posts, 'cmp');
```

Then you need to output the array in another `foreach` loop.

But, as I said, I don't know if wordpress allows this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean 'Authors' when you refer to 'Profiles'.

Once you have all posts in $myposts

```
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
```

you iterate through them all with

```
foreach( $myposts as $key => $post )
```

(notice I've added the $key)

Now you can create you own array with the date as a key

```
$my_array[$myposts[$key]->post_date][] = ...whatevever you want in the end
```

Feel free to add whatever data you want to display in the end. Let's just take the author and title of the posts as an example:

```
$the_item[$myposts[$key]->post_author] = $myposts[$key]->post_title;
$my_array[$myposts[$key]->post_date][] = $the_item;
```

This will result in an array that looks like this:

> ```
> [2007-11-19 22:46:37] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => Array
>             (
>                 [3] => Title
>                 [2] => Another title
>             )
>
>     )
>
> [2007-11-11 11:11:11] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => Array
>             (
>                 [3] => Yet another title
>                 [2] => Foo
>             )
>
>         [1] => Array
>             (
>                 [3] => Bar
>                 [2] => Yuck
>             )
> ```

All posts are now ordered by date with posts by different authors 'mixed'. Feel free to use any of the sort functions (as mentioned above). You might want to add a little randomness by using shuffle()...
In order to display the posts you would go the opposite way: Iterate through your created array and print the data you included (e.g. author, title, content, etc.).
For reference, this is what the post object looks like:

```
myposts:Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 1455
            [post_author] => 3
            [post_date] => 2013-03-27 22:16:33
            [post_date_gmt] => 2013-03-27 22:16:33
            [post_content] => Content
            [post_title] => Title
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => closed
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => title
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2013-03-27 22:16:42
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2013-03-27 22:16:42
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://www.abc.com/wordpress/?p=1455
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => post
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [member_access_visibility] => default
            [filter] => raw
        )
```

Hope this helps you solve your problem!

Cheers

JD

Comment: An even better way is to use a timestamp as array key with a  Strtotime() function. Followed by a simple ksort($array) to order them based on the key (=date)

Comment: @JohnDoeherty The news is a custom field of a post. The post is a full profile of a company so going by the date is meaningless.

Comment: I don't understand: in your question you are asking to order by date so how can going by date be meaningless? Your custom field will be associated withe the post so the post date will still be relevant for your custom field. If you are storing some other date in a custom field the above method would still apply.

Answer (score 0):

You only need the one `get_posts()` function call.

Create a string of all user id's that you want separated by strings.

Now you can add that to your args along with your order:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'author' => '1,2,3,4,5',
    'orderby' => 'date' // date is the default anyway, so shouldn't matter
);
```

Then your `get_posts()` call will include all posts by those authors.

HTH

Comment: I can't sort by date because the post is a full company profile, news is a custom field within that post. So it needs to pull out all the news then sort by the date associated with that news row. I'm using www.advancedcustomfields.com with a repeater field for the news.